Defining array with dimensions without allocation in C
Suppose that I have a pointer of type int*, which I want to interpret as a multidimensional array, e.g., int arr[5][10]. By that I can allow access to it with two indices, e.g. printf("%d\n", arr[0][2]).
This is actually possible if arr is a function argument, even when the caller provides to it with some general pointer, for example:
void do_something(int arr[5][10]) {
    printf("%d\n", arr[0][2]);
}
void func() {
    int *ptr = POINTER_TO_SOMEWHERE;
    do_something(ptr);
}

Actually is it? I'm getting a compiler error, even when casting ptr to int**...
However, if arr[5][10] was defined within the function as a local variable, the array would be actually allocated on the stack.
The question is, whether there is any syntax that will allow the definition of arr within the function, without allocating it, but by just making it a pointer to some already allocated memory, like the function argument?

The sizes here are indeed fixed. I'm actually trying to define the pointer such that the compiler will allow me to use multiple indices, as if it was a multi-dimensional array

https://ideone.com/mhgKhJ

I know it is technically not allowed to treat a multi-dimensional array as a flattened 1-D array, but I'm not sure about treating a 1-D array as a multi-dimensional array.

@IanAbbott why can't you treat a 2D array as a flattened array? just cast it to type*, it works

Getting an error when casting to int** is not surprising if you understand that arrays are not pointers.

@pmg thank you so much. Will appreciate posting it as an answer

@SomethingSomething Just because it works, does not mean it is valid. But it depends if it is a real multi-dimensional array variable being flattened or an allocated object (from malloc etc.). For a real array variable, flattening it would allow access outside the bounds of the innermost array dimensions, which would result in undefined behavior.

"why can't you treat a 2D array as a flattened array?" Because the standard says it's undefined behavior.

Regarding my earlier comment: "…but I'm not sure about treating a 1-D array as a multi-dimensional array." That would break the strict aliasing rule.

For an allocated object (from malloc etc.) of size at least sizeof(int[5][10]) pointed to by int *arr, it is perfectly valid to assign arr[49] = 42; and read the same element back using x = (((int (*)[10])arr)[4][9];. In the first assignment that modifies the allocated object, the effective type of the sizeof(int) modified bytes becomes int. And that same int is read back in the right-hand side of the second assignment.

A side note: you can use a 1D array represent a 2D (or actually an n-D for any n) array by managing the indices "manually". This approach is prefered by many libraries like opencv. It will also solved your current problem.

@IanAbbott: The strict aliasing rule says an object shall be accessed only by an lvalue expression of certain types. If we have some pointer p of type int (*)[10], then, in p[i][j], p[i] is specified to be equivalent to *(p+i). Although this is nominally an array, it is not accessed. Instead, it is automatically converted to a pointer, to which j is added. Then this is equivalent to *(*(p+i)+j), which has type int, and that is used to access an int in memory. This conforms to the strict aliasing rule.

@EricPostpischil Thanks, I realized my mistake by the time I wrote the next comment and realized that you cannot modify an array (because it decays to something that isn't an lvalue in the expression), you can only modify an element of an array.


I have a pointer of type int*, which I want to interpret as a multidimensional array, e.g., int arr[5][10]

Whether or not that is possible/feasible depends on the type pointed at by your int* to begin with, which isn't clear. In general, a 2D array may alias a de-referenced int* and vice versa, but you may not be able to do pointer arithmetic on a 2D array if the original type was something else. I can't speculate about that, you need to show what POINTER_TO_SOMEWHERE is supposed to be.


Actually is it? I'm getting a compiler error, even when casting ptr to int**

No it isn't possible as you describe it. A function with a parameter int arr[5][10] will get adjusted ("decays") by the compiler to a pointer to the first element, type int (*arr)[10]. This type is not compatible with int*.
As for int** it has nothing to do with arrays of arrays what-so-ever. It can only be used to point at the first item in an array of int* pointers, which is something else entirely.


However, if arr[5][10] was defined within the function as a local variable, the array would be actually allocated on the stack.

It isn't, it decays to a pointer to the first element as described above.


The question is, whether there is any syntax that will allow the definition of arr within the function, without allocating it, but by just making it a pointer to some already allocated memory, like the function argument?

That's what int arr[5][10] is already doing, although since C is stricter with type safety of pointers, you can only pass along a pointer to an array of int [10] to this function. Not very flexible.
The better solution is to declare the parameter a pointer to a variable-length array (VLA):
void do_something(size_t x, size_t y, int arr[x][y])

This too decays, but now into a pointer to array of type int (*)[y]. The caller just needs to specify the correct y.
Example:
int main (void)
{
    int arr [2][3]; // actual allocation
    do_something(2, 3, arr); // pass along a pointer
}

...

void do_something(size_t x, size_t y, int arr[x][y])
{
  for(size_t i=0; i<x; i++)
    for(size_t j=0; j<y; j++)
      do_stuff(arr[i][j]);
}



Given @Lundin's example function that uses a VLA:
void do_something(size_t x, size_t y, int arr[x][y])
{
  for(size_t i=0; i<x; i++)
    for(size_t j=0; j<y; j++)
      do_stuff(arr[i][j]);
}

The following code is OK (based on @pmg's example):
int main (void)
{
    int arr1[12] = {0};

    do_something(1, 12, (int (*)[12]) arr1);
    do_something(2, 6, (int (*)[6]) arr1);
    do_something(3, 4, (int (*)[4]) arr1);
    do_something(4, 3, (int (*)[3]) arr1);
    do_something(6, 2, (int (*)[2]) arr1);
    do_something(12, 1, (int (*)[1]) arr1);
}

The following code is not OK because it has several out-of-bounds array accesses to the inner array:
int main (void)
{
    int arr2[4][3] = {0};

    do_something(1, 12, (int (*)[12]) arr2); // out of bounds access to inner array
    do_something(2, 6, (int (*)[6]) arr2); // out of bounds access to inner array
    do_something(3, 4, (int (*)[4]) arr2); // out of bounds access to inner array
    do_something(4, 3, (int (*)[3]) arr2); // OK (the type cast is not needed here)
    do_something(6, 2, (int (*)[2]) arr2); // See Note 1.
    do_something(12, 1, (int (*)[1]) arr2); // OK
}

Note 1: Treating an int[4][3] as an int[6][2] will result in some of the int[2] inner arrays straddling across the boundaries of the original int[3] arrays, resulting in out-of-bounds access to some of the inner arrays. For example, when i=1, j=1, do_stuff(arr[i][j]) will be out of bounds because arr[i][0] maps to the original arr2[0][2] so arr[i][j] in effect accesses arr2[0][3] which is out-of-bounds of the original inner array (even though it maps to the same element as arr2[1][0]). To be honest, I'm not sure if do_stuff(arr[i][j]) is OK for any of the cases where the new inner dimension does not divide into the original inner dimension.
But the following code is OK because it uses an allocated object with no declared type:
int main (void)
{
    int (* pa)[3] = calloc(12, sizeof(int));
  
    if (!pa)
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    do_something(1, 12, (int (*)[12]) pa);
    do_something(2, 6, (int (*)[6]) pa);
    do_something(3, 4, (int (*)[4]) pa);
    do_something(4, 3, (int (*)[3]) pa);
    do_something(6, 2, (int (*)[2]) pa);
    do_something(12, 1, (int (*)[1]) pa);
}



I have a pointer of type int*, which I want to interpret (that is points to) as a multidimensional array, e.g., int arr[5][10]. By that I can allow access to it with two indices, e.g. printf("%d\n", arr[0][2]).

#define ARRAY_ROW 5
#define ARRAY_COL 10

size_t access_row = 0;
size_t access_col = 2;

int *arr = malloc(sizeof arr[0] * ARRAY_ROW * ARRAY_COL];

// Assign the array elements with TBD code.

printf("%d\n", arr[access_row * ARRAY_COL + access_col]);

Or
union {
  int arr2[ARRAY_ROW][ARRAY_COL];
  int arr1[ARRAY_ROW * ARRAY_COL];
} x;

x.arr1[access_row * ARRAY_COL + access_col] = tbd;
printf("%d\n", arr2[access_row][access_col]);



Actually is it? I'm getting a compiler error, even when casting ptr to int**...

why getting a compiler error is that the code you provided currently pass a plain int* pointer, but the function does not know how to interpret the memory correctly due to the function expects a pointer to an array of arrays, instead of a single pointer. What you can try, in the function, to define the parameter as int (*arr)[10], a pointer to an array of 10 int elements.
void do_something(int (*arr)[10]) {
    printf("%d\n", arr[0][2]);
}

void func() {
    int *ptr = malloc(5 * 10 * sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < 5 * 10; i++) {
        ptr[i] = i + 1;
    }

    do_something((int (*)[10])ptr);

    free(ptr);
}


You are allowed to do this:
int (*my_matrix)[5][10] = malloc(sizeof *my_matrix);

if you want to dynamically allocate a matrix, this will allow you to access your elements as (*my_matrix)[2][3] for example.
But if you want to generalize that to a variable dimensioned matrix, you will not be able, you need to think that an array type is bounded at compilation time with the dimensions of the array, this meaning that
typedef mat1[5][10];

and
typedef mat2[7][30];

are two different, incompatible types.
Having the dimensions fixed at runtime would open the possibility (and the need to implement it) of having an infinite, unbounded number of types in the application without the need to recompile the program.  This implies facts that fall well out of the minimum overhead from the compiler statement, requiring the language to maintain (and observe) array dimensions at runtime.
So, in the end, if you want to do:
int (*my_matrix)[R][C] = malloc(sizeof *my_matrix); /* WRONG WRONG WRONG */

being R and/or C dynamically asignable variables, you will end in a dynamic type (better, in an infinite set of types, for each of the possible dimensions of your array), which would require to maintain the dimensions of the array at runtime, along with the variable data.
On other side, is quite easy to implement a variable sized matrix with static typing.  You can do that with pointers, by having an array of pointers to point to the rows, then an array of cells on each pointer holding the bidimensional array:
char **matrix = malloc(rows * (sizeof *matrix));
for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    matrix[i] = malloc(cols * (sizeof *matrix[i]));
}

and then you can refer to the cell elements using normal matrix notation, as in matrix[the_row][the_column];.

Have I been downvoted? sure? before the answer was complete?  Thank you to the anonymous downvoter!!!! :)
